# Electric field fluctuations in QM optics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-optics

In a text I am using, it states the following: Given that $$\langle n| \hat{E}^2_x(z,t)| n \rangle = 2 \varepsilon_0^2 \sin^2(kz) \bigg( n + \frac{1}{2} \bigg) $$ The fluctuations in the electric field may be characterized by the variance $$\langle ( \Delta \hat{E}_x(z,t))^2 \rangle = \langle \hat{E}^2_x(z,t) \rangle - \langle \hat{E}_x(z,t) \rangle^2$$ or by the standard deviation $\Delta E_x = \langle ( \Delta E_x(z,t)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, which is sometimes referred to as the uncertainty of the field. For the number state $|n \rangle$ we have $$\Delta E_x = \sqrt{2 \varepsilon_0} \sin (kz) \bigg( n + \frac{1}{2} \bigg)^\frac{1}{2}.$$ Note the even when $n = 0$, the field has fluctuations, the so-called vacuum fluctuations. Now the number states $|n \rangle$ are taken to represent a state of the field containing $n$ photons. Yet as we have seen, the average field is zero. This is all in accordance with the uncertainty principle because the number operator $\hat{n}$ does not commute with the electric field: $$[ \hat{n}, \hat{E}_x] = \varepsilon_0 \sin(kz) (\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\hat{a})$$ Thus $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{E}_x$ are complementary quantities for which their respective uncertainties obey the inequality $$\Delta n \Delta E_x \geq \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon_0 | \sin (kz)|| \langle \hat{a}^{\dagger} - \hat{a} \rangle |$$

For a number state $|n \rangle$, the right-hand side vanishes but $\Delta n = 0$ as well. If the field were accurately known, then the number of photons would be uncertain.

**Questions**: What is the importance of what is defined as *fluctuations in the electric field*? How does this operator notion of an electric field relate to the classical notion of the electric field as a wave? You simply go from a wave function to an operator seems a bit arbitrary?

Thanks.

Comment: This means the fluctuation of the electric field is associated with the fluctuation in the photon number.

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell Okay thanks. Do you maybe know what the significance of the observation "For a number state $|n \rangle$, the right-hand side vanishes but $\Delta n = 0$ as well" is?